# Database input sanitisation with PHP forms

Tags: php, mysql

I sanitise the data I receive from the form in the following way:

```
$gender = filter_var($_POST['gender'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$firstName = filter_var($_POST['firstName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$lastName = filter_var($_POST['lastName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$message = filter_var($_POST['comment'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$address = filter_var($_POST['address'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$numBrochures = (int) filter_var($_POST['quantity'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

The relevant SQL queries that insert the data are as follows:

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users(firstName, lastName, email, gender) VALUES('$firstName', '$lastName', '$email', '$gender')") == TRUE) {
  logSuccess($file, "Adding user");
}
else {
  logError($file, "Adding user", mysqli_error($conn));
}

$userId = $conn->query("SELECT `userId` FROM users WHERE `firstName` = '$firstName' AND `lastName` = '$lastName' AND `email` = '$email'")->fetch_object()->userId;
if ($userId == false) {
  logError($file, "Fetching user id", mysqli_error($conn));

}

if (mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO brochureOrders(userId, address, numBrochures, message) VALUES('$userId', '$address', '$numBrochures', '$message')") == TRUE) {
  logSuccess($file, "Brochure Order");
  $sendConfirmationEmail = true;
}
else {
  logError($file, "Brochure Order", mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

However, in my database, I see entries like the following:

```
address = "vz8y8E  gghwptvvzuak, [url=http://ytvsmximkjnp.com/]ytvsmximkjnp[/url], [link=http://hiabgyvsjifp.com/]hiabgyvsjifp[/link], http://tyvylndqitoy.com/"
```

Shouldn't the following have taken care of this?

```
$address = filter_var($_POST['address'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing incorrectly here?

Comment: This makes me cry... why not use prepared statements :/

Comment: `filter_var` with the 'FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING' filter just strips tags and (optionally) strips or encodes special characters. What were you hoping that it would do?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: I was hoping for it to remove URLs.

Comment: It doesn't do that. As Arian suggests, you should begin using prepared statements via PDO immediately to protect against SQL injection attacks, and write or find a better filtering scheme to remove URLs as needed.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: Yes, I will do that.

Comment: @Arian: I will switch to using prepared statements.

Comment: @rahulthewall I can make a function that will fix the url data, can you post what you expect it to look like though?

Comment: @Arian I would like to clean up the PHP scripts by using prepared statements and then give sanitising the input a shot on my own first. If I encounter bugs, I will come back.

Comment: @Arian I have switched to prepared queries, but the error was that I forgot that empty string is not equal to NULL. After adding that check, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the OP stated in the comments he wants to switch to prepared statement, I thought I'd show him an example.

Instead of something like this:

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users(firstName, lastName, email, gender) VALUES('$firstName', '$lastName', '$email', '$gender')") == TRUE) {
  logSuccess($file, "Adding user");
}
else {
  logError($file, "Adding user", mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Do something like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, email, gender) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $firstName, $lastName, $email, $gender);
    $stmt->exeucte();
    $stmt->close();
}else die("Failed to prepare!");
```

and this

```
$query = "SELECT `userId` FROM users WHERE `firstName` = ? AND `lastName` = ? AND `email` = ?";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $firstName, $lastName, $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($userId);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close()
}else die("Failed to prepare!");
```

Comment: This is a good improvement to prevent SQL injection attacks, but be aware that it doesn't address the core issue as stated in comments: "I was hoping for it to remove URLs."

Comment: @GeorgeCummins yeah i know, but the OP stated in the comments he wanted to switch to prepared statements, so I just wanted to show him an example of what it would look like.